# Insert a list into numpy-based matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I want to insert a list into numpy-based matrix in a specific index. For instance, the following code (python 2.7) is supposed to insert the list `[5,6,7]` into `M` in the second place:

```
M = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
M = np.asarray(M)
X = np.insert(M, 1, [5,6,7])
print(X)
```

This, however, does not output what I would like. It causes to mess up the matrix `M` by merging all lists into one single list. How can I achieve adding any list in any place of numpy-based matrix?

Thank you

Comment: Why, *why* do you want to do this? `numpy` is meant to work with fixed-length numberic type arrays. It provides *true* multidimensional arrays, so ragged arrays are not possible without using the `object` dtype, which almost defeats the purpose of numpy. Why not just use a `list` of `list`s?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In fact, I am supposed to add new list to fixed matrix `M` in various position inside a loop based on my algorithm. That's why I thought so

Comment: Why would you think this is a good use-case for `numpy`? Why not just a `list`? Do do this, you'll need an `object` dtype array, which is essentially, a bad python `list`

Comment: I agree with you

Answer (score 0):

```
In [80]: M = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
    ...: M1 = np.asarray(M)
    ...:
```

List insert:

```
In [81]: M[1:2] = [[5,6,7]]
In [82]: M
Out[82]: [[0, 0], [5, 6, 7], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
```

Contrast the array made from the original M and the modified one:

```
In [83]: M1
Out[83]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1]])
In [84]: np.array(M)
Out[84]: 
array([list([0, 0]), list([5, 6, 7]), list([1, 0]), list([1, 1])],
      dtype=object)
```

The second one is not a 2d array.

`np.insert` without an axis ravels things (check the docs)

```
In [85]: np.insert(M1,1,[5,6,7])
Out[85]: array([0, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1])
```

If I specify an axis it complains about a mismatch in shapes:

```
In [86]: np.insert(M1,1,[5,6,7],axis=0)
   ...
   5071         new[slobj] = arr[slobj]
   5072         slobj[axis] = slice(index, index+numnew)
-> 5073         new[slobj] = values
   5074         slobj[axis] = slice(index+numnew, None)
   5075         slobj2 = [slice(None)] * ndim

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1,3) into shape (1,2)
```

It creates a (1,2) shape slot to receive the new value, but [5,6,7] won't fit.

```
In [87]: np.insert(M1,1,[5,6],axis=0)
Out[87]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [5, 6],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = numpy.array([input().split() for i in range(int(input().split()[0]))])
print(arr)
```

**INPUT:**

```
2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[['1' '2' '3' '4'] 
['5' '6' '7' '8']]
```